# How to include S3 superclass as slot in S4 object?

Tags: r, r-s4

I want to have a slot containing an S3 superclass, for example `connection`.  Most `connection` instances are actually subtypes, such as `textConnection` or `pipe`.

It seems like each subtype must be declared with `setOldType` seperately, otherwise the `new` function will not accept the connection.

To make this more concrete:

```
setOldClass("connection")
setOldClass(c("pipe", "connection"))
setOldClass(c("textConnection", "connection"))

setClass("Thing", 
         slots = list(handle = "connection")
)

thing1 <- new("Thing", handle=textConnection("hiarylah"))
thing2 <- new("Thing", handle=pipe("cat ~/iris.csv"))
```

Is there a way to declare Thing so that it accepts anything that inherits from connection? I don't want to have to add a line every time a new subclass is invented.